# Where can I find the keyboard shortcut settings for the brightness keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, keyboard-backlight

Why does the Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts not show keyboard or screen dimming and brightening controls?

Is this something that simply the community hasn't written the code to display it for? Or is it located somewhere else? Or maybe under a name that isn't descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the keyboard/screen dimming and brightening controls are not considered as shortcuts, the shortcuts in this settings menu are ones that you can add for a specific(personnalized) action, not an action that affects the hardware(brightening...)

Comment: If that's the case, then why would they consider volume a setting? That doesn't seem consistent to me.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you have? Do you want to change the shortcut of brightning controls? or is it just not working for you?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 + GNOME 3.24.2. On my wireless keyboard the F keys simply don't work. But if I could get them working I would then want to re-map those on my **internal** keyboard so it matches my wireless keyboard.